# Python tkinter not detecting mouse click on tops of lables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so I'm creating chess in tkinter, I would like to detect the mouse coords when clicked.

But it appears it won't detect clicks through a label.
So when I bind to the main window, it works.

```
self.board = Canvas(self.window,width=768,height=768)
self.backgroundimage = PhotoImage(file="chessboard.png")
self.window.bind('<Button-1>',self.func)
```

However, it detects mouse clicks when clicked off the board. I want it to only detect mouse clicks inside the board frame.

When I do this

```
self.board.bind('<Button-1>',self.func)
```

it no longer detects mouse clicks :/  UNLESS, I remove the lable. So it won't detects clicks through labels or images, unless it's bound to the main window. I want the coords/pixles to be relative to the frame I'm clicking inside of, because obviously I'll have a Board frame, and another frame on the side for actions like request takeback, resign, etc..

Comment: It's quite difficult to help without seeing the relevant code. Please provide a [mre] so I can see the layout of buttons and labels.

Comment: "UNLESS, I remove the lable." **what** label? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the labels and images with buttons

For Label `self.testbuttonwithtext = tk.Button(text='your text', border=0, function=self.func)`

For Images `self.testbuttonwithimage = tk.Button(border=0, image='the path of your image here, function=self.func)`

I Hope this help you and feel free to ask again if this didn't help you.